# Licence in a reproduced figure caption

Tags: copyright, elsevier

I am writing a thesis at a university. In my thesis, I directly copy a figure from an article published on Sciencedirect. I have obtained permission to use this figure over Rightslink. I now would like to add a caption to the figure that looks like this:

Figure reproduced with permission from *Author* (*Year*); copyright *Year* **Copyright**.

However, I have no idea which **Copyright** I should mention. Since I had to obtain permission, I assume it is not a CC license.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I am using the following guideline to write the caption:

[Guideline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9DgU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention *ScienceDirect*, I guess the publisher (and owner of any copyright claims) is *Elsevier*.

If you follow the guideline in the caption you linked to, you could therefore write:

> Figure reproduced with permission from *Author* (*YYYY*); copyright *YYYY* Elsevier.

As regards a possible *Creative Commons* license (as is visible in the caption you linked to as `CC BY-SA 4.0`), this will likely depend on the journal and/or article. I would recommend you to fetch the DOI of that article and insert it into CrossRef's API at `https://api.crossref.org/works/THE-DOI-HERE`. Then take a look at the `license` field. [An Elsevier Open Access article I randomly looked at](https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1016/j.abrep.2020.100325), for instance, carries the license `CC BY-NC-ND 4.0` according to the API.

However, if the article you take the Figure from is *not* an Open Access one, then probably you do not have to list any particular license at all.